# How can I set a landscape layout just for tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Imagine I've a layout folder named `layout-port`. This layout contains the two-layouts you can see in the picture below (handset).
In the other hand, I've a `layout` folder which is used when the screen orientation is not in portrait mode, so it's in landscape.

[image]

However, when I rotate a device with a small screen, it's going to use the portrait layout, but as the screen is so small, its not optimal and it doesn't look good as the two fragments layout is mainly focused for atleast 600dp tablets.

So the question is, 
**Is there any way I can use a qualifier to set a Landscape layout for smallest width higher than 600?**

I've been checking the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but it doesn't seem to be able to combine smallest width & orientation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the tablet layout in your `res/layout-w600dp` or whatever smallest width you want to support for the two pane layout.

Comment: Guess this is the correct answer. As android developer website states: This is often useful to determine whether to use a multi-pane layout, because even on a tablet device, you often won't want the same multi-pane layout for portrait orientation as you do for landscape. Thus, you can use this to specify the minimum width required for the layout, instead of using both the screen size and orientation qualifiers together. 

**Notice that its W and not SW**

Comment: please let me know if i've to make 7 inch tablet (1280*800 resolution) app in ladscape mode , then should i prefer layout-sw600dp or layout-w600dp or layout-w600dp-land ?

Answer (score 16):

I think what you really want is to declare a folder...

```
layout-w600dp-land
```

this will be invoked only if your tablet or w600dp device is in landscape mode.  Basically you can combine qualifiers `w600dp` with `land`.

Comment: please let me know if i've to make 7 inch tablet (1280*800 resolution) app in ladscape mode , then should i prefer layout-sw600dp or layout-w600dp or layout-w600dp-land ?

Answer (score 2):

You could just ignore the `-port` qualifier.
Generally if the device has 600dp (or whatever number you choose), you could show the two-pane layout. Does it really matter if it is in landscape mode or portrait if there is enough space on the screen?

So in general you can put your layout for small screens in the `layout` folder and use `layout-sw600dp` for the larger layout.

Comment: I guess it would be a better approach using width instead of smallest width. So if the actual width (even if in landscape or portrait) is higher than X we will know the two-fragments layout will look good.